# Change scaling order WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, datagrid

I have a WPF application that needs to be sort of responsive. What I want to have is a `DataGrid` inside a `Grid`. When the window scales down, I want the `Grid` to resize first, and then the `DataGrid`. Here is what I achieved so far:

[image]

In the gif on top you can see that the `Grid` resizes first, and when it reaches it's minimum scaling size, it goes over the bottom `DataGrid`. Not exactly what I want because I want to scale the layout first, then show a scrollbar in the `DataGrid` instead of the layout just going over it. So I tried the following:

[image]

Right here you can see that it shows the scrollbars like I want. The only thing is that it first resizes the DataGrid, and when it's done resizing the DataGrid, it starts to resize the Grid. I want it to be the other way around, first resize the grid, then resize the DataGrid and show the Scrollbars. So basically I'm searching for a solution that does the following:

1. Scale the window which scales the Grid.
2. Scale the grid till it's minimum size
3. When it has reached the minimum size and it's still getting smaller, show scrollbar in DataGrid.

So that comes down to the first Gif from this question, followed by scrollbars in the DataGrid

Is there any way to do this? It seems like I'm very close since it's a combination of those two things but I don't know how. Here's my code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Grid.Column="0">
  <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="20"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
      <RowDefinition Name="DataGridRow" Height="*" MaxHeight="240" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="24">Test</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Test"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
    <Label Grid.Row="7" Content="Test"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="9" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Separator Grid.Row="11"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="13" Content="Test" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="15">
      <DataGrid
          RowHeight="40"
           CanUserAddRows="False"
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            HeadersVisibility="None"
            GridLinesVisibility="None"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
              </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
          </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think that `RowDefinition` `Height` defaults to `Auto`, so both of your row definitions `Heights` are set as `Auto`. Try using `Height="*"` on your `DataGridRow` `RowDefinition`.

Comment: @Kirenenko if I set `Height="*"` and `maxheight="240"`in my RowDefinition, I get the same result as in the first gif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In those cases where solving the layout equation is no longer possible with the default building blocks, you can 
do the calculations yourself. Letting a converter calculate the available space that's left.

The remaining problem is twofold:

1. The `DataGrid` may only shrink when the star sized rows have
   `ActualHeight` 0.

   Solution: `DataGrid.Style` that sets `dataGrid.MaxHeight` when
   `triggerGrid.ActualHeight` = 0 (`triggerGrid` occupies a star sized
   row).
2. When we're giving a `MinHeight` to `DataGridRow` it won't shrink when
   the `dataGrid.ActualHeight` shrinks (it steals the shrunk height
   back).

   Solution: `RowDefinition.Style` that sets its `MinHeight` to
   `dataGrid.ActualHeight` when `triggerGrid.ActualHeight` = 0 and to the
   fixed value otherwise.

I've set the Controls' `BackGround` colors to illustrate when the star sized height (remaining white space) becomes 0.

```
<Window 

    ...

    Width="200" Height="450">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HeightConverter x:Key="HeightConverter" />
        <local:IsEqualToZeroConverter x:Key="IsEqualToZeroConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <!--MainGrid-->
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="5"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="dataGridRow" Height="Auto">
                    <RowDefinition.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=triggerGrid, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualToZeroConverter}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter  Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=triggerGrid, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualToZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter  Property="MinHeight" Value="80.0"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RowDefinition.Style>
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="bigLabel" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="24" Background="LightGray">Test</Label>
            <Label x:Name="regularLabel" Grid.Row="3" Content="Test" Background="LightGray"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Row="5" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="LightGray" />
            <Label Grid.Row="7" Content="Test" Background="LightGray"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="9" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="LightGray"/>
            <Separator x:Name="separator" Grid.Row="11"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="13" Content="Test"  Background="LightGray"/>
            <!--TriggerGrid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="14" x:Name="triggerGrid"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="15">
                <DataGrid
                    x:Name="dataGrid"
                    RowHeight="40"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                    HeadersVisibility="None"
                    GridLinesVisibility="None"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=triggerGrid}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="MaxHeight">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}">
                                                <Binding ElementName="mainGrid" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="bigLabel" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="regularLabel" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="comboBox" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="separator" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Style>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Converters**

```
public class HeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // only 1 check at startup (Debugging)
        if ((double)values[1] == 0.0) return 0.0;

        double mainGridHeight       = (double)values[0];
        double bigLabelHeight       = (double)values[1];
        double regularLabelHeight   = (double)values[2];
        double comboBoxHeight       = (double)values[3];
        double separatorHeight      = (double)values[4];

        double dataGridHeight = mainGridHeight - bigLabelHeight - 2 * (regularLabelHeight + comboBoxHeight) - regularLabelHeight - separatorHeight;

        if (dataGridHeight > 0.0) return dataGridHeight; else return 0.0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class IsEqualToZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value == 0.0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact answer.  But, it will give an idea to achieve your need.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />            
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel>                        
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="240">DataGrid</TextBlock>
        <Separator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Hope that helps.